# Self referencing struct declarations

Tags: c, struct, language-lawyer

I'm trying to understand what some example in the Standard mean.

`N2346::6.7.2.3/p12`(emp. mine):

> **EXAMPLE 2** To illustrate the use of prior declaration of a tag to specify a pair of mutually referential structures, the declarations
>
> ```
> struct s1 { struct s2 *s2p; /* ... */ }; // D1
> struct s2 { struct s1 *s1p; /* ... */ }; // D2
> ```
>
> specify a pair of structures that contain pointers to each other.
> **Note, however, that if `s2` were already declared as a tag in an**
> **enclosing scope, the declaration `D1` would refer to it, not to the**
> **tag `s2` declared in `D2`. To eliminate this context sensitivity, the**
> **declaration**
>
> ```
> struct s2;
> ```
>
> **can be inserted ahead of `D1`.** This declares a new tag `s2` in the
> inner scope; the declaration `D2` then completes the specification of
> the new type.

I don't really understand what the emphasized part means.

If a tag `s2` would be declared in the enclosing scope e.g. as follows:

```
struct s2; //previous visible declaration
struct s1 { struct s2 *s2p; /* ... */ }; // D1
struct s2 { struct s1 *s1p; /* ... */ }; // D2
```

Then both of the declaration and the definition would specify the same type.
`N2346::6.7.2.3/p8`:

> If a type specifier of the form
>
> ```
> struct-or-union identifier
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> enum identifier
> ```
>
> occurs other than as part of one of the above forms, and a declaration
> of the identifier as a tag is visible, then it specifies the same type
> as that other declaration, and does not redeclare the tag.

And the type is the `struct s2 { struct s1 *s1p; /* ... */ };` defined at `D2`.

So what does the Standard by inserting the declaration ahead of `D1` to eliminate context sensitivity. I didn't see any context sensetivity here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you created only has one scope.  To demonstrate the point they're making, you need to have a nested scope.  For example, the following complete program demonstrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    int     a;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct bar {
        int     b;
        struct foo *ptr;
    };

    struct foo {
        int     c;
        struct bar *ptr;
    };

    struct bar x;

    printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(struct foo), sizeof(*x.ptr));

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this on my system, I get:

```
16 4
```

The reason these two sizes aren't the same is because the first size is from the local definition of `struct foo`, while `struct bar` is using the previously-declared global definition of `struct foo`, since the definition of `struct bar` preceded the local definition of `struct foo`.

Comment: How is it possible to redefine a struct with the same tag name? Didn't know that it was even possible... Could you please point out a relevant Standard section?

Comment: It seems I found it _Two declarations of structure, union, or enumerated types which are in different scopes or use different tags declare distinct types._

Comment: @SomeName Right, they're scoped just like any other declaration.  After the end of the function, the original global definition would again be available.

Comment: @TomKarzes: They are not scoped quite “just like” any other declaration. There are some weird rules about whether a structure or union definition declares a new type or not. For example, there is a difference between `struct foo x;` and `struct foo;`. The former does not declare a new `struct foo` type even if it is in a nested scope from a currently visible previous `struct foo`, but the latter does declare a new type.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The difference you mention has to do with when a new structure type is declared vs. when an existing structure type is referenced.  That's independent of the scoping.  It just affects when a new structure tag is introduced into a scope.

Comment: You can argue there is some technical definition of “scope” that includes only what the identifier refers to and where and does not include how the declaration is made, but telling a student that structure tag scoping works “just like” other scoping may mislead them because of the weird rules about whether a declaration declares a new type or not. It is not a good statement to make.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My statement was correct.  I never said the declaration syntax is the same.  I said the scoping is the same, which it is.  Scope simply describes where a given name binding is valid.  Your statement, claiming that the scoping isn't the same, was incorrect.  Scoping vs. declaration syntax are independent concepts.

Comment: It is not useful to declare pedantic correctness with some definition (but not others) when it has deleterious practical effects. Misleading students with “true” statements is bad. And scoping does not exist independently of declarations, so it is not incorrect to say that scoping of tags does not work “just like” scoping of object identifiers when they cannot be made exactly alike because their declarations must differ.

Comment: @EricPostpischil _For example, there is a difference between `struct foo x;` and `struct foo;`._ Interesting point. Have never thought that the former might or might not declare a new type `struct foo`. Does the Standard explain such case?

Comment: @SomeName: C 2018 6.7.2.3 paragraphs 6-9 discuss whether a particular form of a structure or union declaration newly declares a tag or not. Largely: `struct foo` newly declares `foo` if it is followed by the structure definition (list of member types in `{` and `}`), is followed immediately by a semicolon (no declarators, as in `struct foo x;` or `struct foo *p;`), or `foo` is not already visible as a structure or union tag.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `6.7.2.3/p8`: _If a type specifier of the form `struct-or-union identifier`
occurs other than as part of one of the above forms, and no other declaration of the identifier as a tag is visible, then it declares an incomplete structure or union type, and declares the identifier as the tag of that type._ Note that the form is without a semicolon after the identifier. So the paragraph applies to the case `struct foo x;` meaning that it **does declare** _an incomplete structure type_. What's wrong here in the reasoning?

Comment: @SomeName That's true, but only if "no other declaration of the identifier as a tag is visible".  If an existing declaration of that struct/union tag is still "visible" (i.e., available in that scope), then it refers to the existing tag, and does not introduce a new struct/union type.

Comment: @TomKarzes Got it, thanks. Tag declaration semantic turned out to be much subtler than it seemed.